# how can i fetch the information from json youtube-dl when i use --get-id

Tags: json, youtube-dl

i have problem when i try to get the information from json file ($output)
When i use youtube-dl .
 i need webpage_url from my json file 
my code is

```
$output = shell_exec('youtube-dl -J https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLANMHOrJaFxPCjR2enLZBRgtZgjtXJ0MJ' );
$youtubeId = json_decode($output);
$youtubeId = $youtubeId->webpage_url;

echo $youtubeId;
```

Comment: You do not need youtube-dl , curl + sed + awk... [Understanding the YouTube API's JSON-C responses](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses)

Comment: my real goal to get all the link which related to my playlist video
and i didn't saw it in api

Answer (score 2):

For a playlist and the `-J` option, you must loop through the 'entries' array.

```
$output = shell_exec('youtube-dl -J --playlist-items 1-3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLANMHOrJaFxPCjR2enLZBRgtZgjtXJ0MJ' );
$playlist = json_decode($output);
foreach ($playlist->entries as $vid) {
    $youtubeId = $vid->webpage_url;
    echo $youtubeId;
}
```

Each element therein contains the properties you expect, like `webpage_url`, as each element is a video.

You may use `--playlist-items 1-3` to restrict grabbed videos to e.g. the 1st through 3rd vids of a playlist.

For all available command line options see [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options).